# Image won't display in app when using bitmap in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, bitmap

I'm attempting to write my first application and am having issues with using images. I am able to get the image to display in the app but found due to its high resolution the load time was slow. I went to add a bit map and found sample code from developers.android.com but when I implemented it the image was no longer seen. The image view is still there to my knowledge since the text set to be directly below it is in the right place.

I'll state that also I am unsure where to properly implement the bit map code and it may be in the wrong class file.

Activity where picture is shown:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_ion"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.michael.titanfall2apptest.Ion">

<ImageView
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ion"
    android:id="@+id/ionimageView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_width="175dp"
    android:layout_height="175dp"/>

<TextView
    android:text="Ion"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ionimageView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/textView"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Class for Activity:

```
public class Ion extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ion);
    ImageView ionImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ionimageView);
    ionImageView.setImageBitmap(
            decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(),        R.id.ionimageView, 500, 500));
}

public static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }
    Log.d("test", "Look here");
    return inSampleSize;
}

public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
                                                     int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}
```

Any resource suggestions would also be appreciated. I haven't quite found a video explaining this exactly.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because, you pass id of ImageView, which is only a container for image:
`ionImageView.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.id.ionimageView, 500, 500));`

You need pass id of drawable image (not ImageView):
`ionImageView.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ion, 500, 500));`

Remove also:

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/ion"
```

in your layout.

Comment: That makes sense. I saw I was using R.id instead of R.drawable. It now recognizes ion in drawable but when I create the image view  like this 'ImageView ionImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.drawable.ion);' it says it expects a resource type of id, id for ion. Am I creating the view wrong?

Comment: Yes, it is wrong. For findViewById() method use id of view (ImageView in your case) eg. R.id.ionimageView. For drawable use drawable id: R.drawable.ion.

Comment: I'm still having issues. I am confused if I am suppose to pass in the image or the activity for the imageview. If I do, ImageView ionImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.drawable.ion2); it yells at me because ion2 is a drawable not a view. So I think I'm trying to do 2 different things here and have the wrong syntax.

Comment: R.drawable.something - id of drawable named "something" (e.g. picture).
R.id.something - id of view declared in xml layout (e.g. TextView, ImageView, FrameLayout).
findViewById() - method, which allows get your View inside Java code, and then do something with it. 
You have: 
ImageView ionImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.drawable.ion2)
It means, that you want get your ImageView from id of picture (R.drawable.ion2 is id of picture not View) - it is wrong. You need to get your ImageView from id of ImageView: ImageView ionImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ionimageView);